# I need to make an Android App which will retrieve data from a web database server, so what type of access (telnet, ftp etc) do i need?

Tags: android, database, webserver

I am a beginner in developing android apps, and I need to know which kind of access do I need in order to retrieve data from a web database server to an android app.

Comment: this isnt the place to come for questions like this. you need to do some research yourself, may I introduce you to someone? www.google.com

Comment: this might help https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting

Answer (score 0):

You can use Firebase from Google for better database support for your app. You can easily do that using [Firebase Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I am supposed to use a webserver provided by my university, which is a LAMP server. So, Firebase is not an option.